# Issue with Bokeh AutocompleteInput in jupyter notebook cell

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, bokeh

I'm using an AutocompleteInput widget in a jupyter notebook. The autocompletion itself is working fine but I have an issue with the output.

[Issue circled in red](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kdUWC.png)

Is it possible somehow to be able to see the ouput of the autocompletion without having to scroll (which is really not user friendly) ? (resizing the output cell of the notebook, autofiting the cell, option of the AutocompleteInput widet)

this is what i've done at the moment:

```
input_widget  = AutocompleteInput(completions=list(df_competences['libelleCompetence']), title='Chercher une compétence', placeholder='Chercher une compétence', sizing_mode='scale_height', css_classes=['my_autocomplete_class'])
show(input_widget)
```

I've been looking a lot of possibilities but not founding a way to do this...

Answer (score 0):

In case someone fall on the same issue as me, here is how I manged to fix it:

I'm getting the HTML code generated by bokeh, remove the class used by bokeh and replacing it with my own one. Then, you just need to create your own css class to make the autocompletion output suitable.

Here is the code:

```
from IPython.display import HTML
input_widget  = AutocompleteInput(completions=list(df_competences['libelleCompetence']), title='Chercher une compétence: ', placeholder='Chercher une compétence', sizing_mode='scale_both', css_classes=['my_autocomplete_class'])

script, div = components(input_widget)

div = div.replace('bk-root', 'my_class')
div = div.replace('<div class="my_class"', '<div class="my_class" style="width: 100%; max_height: 500;"')

HTML(script + div)
```

Comment: what is your `components` in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Add a display HTML command, where you specify the *min-height* of the displayed suggestion box:

```
from IPython.core.display import display, HTML
input_widget  = AutocompleteInput(completions=list(df_competences['libelleCompetence']), title='Chercher une compétence', placeholder='Chercher une compétence', sizing_mode='scale_height', css_classes=['my_autocomplete_class'])
display(HTML('<style> .bk-root[id] { min-height:100pt } </style>'))
show(input_widget)
```